# Node (maven) to deploy the application to several environments

Tags: maven, spring-boot, jelastic

On `Jelastic`, I created a node for building an application (maven), there are several identical environments `(NGINX + Spring Boot)`, the *difference* is in binding to its database and configured `SSL`.

The task is to ensure that after building the application `(* .jar)`, deploy at the same time go to these several environments, how to implement it?

When editing a project, it is possible to specify only one environment, multi-selection is not provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it`s allowed to specify just one environment

We suggest creating a few environments using one Repository branch, and run updates by API https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Vcs-method-Update pushing whole code to VCS.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to use [CloudScripting](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/quick-start/) technology for attaching custom logic to [onAfterBuildProject](https://docs.cloudscripting.com/creating-manifest/events/#onafterbuildproject) event and deploying the project to additional environments after build is complete. Please check this JPS as an [example of the code syntax](https://github.com/jelastic-jps/thorntail/blob/master/microservice-skinny-jar/manifest.jps#L64). Most likely you will need to use [DeployProject](https://docs.jelastic.com/api/#!/api/environment.Deployment-method-DeployProject) API method.